# .htaccess rewrite module not working under Apache in windows

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, .htaccess

I am attempting to redirect requests to a folder back up to a single file, `index.py` in my root directory in my Apache server. So far nothing is working.  Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !index\.py
RewriteRule . index.py [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is still letting me feed it URLs like `www.example.com/files/testfile.zip` and download. It needs to go back up to `index.py`. I have uncommented the `mod_rewrite.co` line in `httpd.conf`. This is in Windows.

Comment: are you activate the rewrite module in apache ->apache module -> rewrite_module ?
it's work on wampserver.

Comment: In general, [don't use `.htaccess`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when)  and place your rewrite rules in the main Apache configuration file

Comment: "I have uncommented the mod_rewrite.co line in httpd.conf" - And presumably you also restarted the server? And .htaccess files are enabled with `AllowOverride ...` in the server config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is still letting me feed it URLs like `www.example.com/files/testfile.zip` and download.

The directives you have posted explicitly exclude URLs that map to existing files on the filesystem. So yes, you would be allowed you to access `/files/testfile.zip` (a physical file) and download it. (Specifically, the `RewriteRule` will only apply to non-existent files.)

However, there are other issues with the directives you have posted which suggests this is not working correctly... where is this .htaccess file located?

If this .htaccess file is in the document root, then it will match *every* request, not just requests for files in the subdirectory.

If the .htaccess file is in the subdirectory, then any successful rewrites will rewrite to `index.py` in that subdirectory, not the document root.

To *internally rewrite* **all** requests in a particular subdirectory to `index.py` in the document root, then try the following in the .htaccess file in that subdirectory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ /index.py [L]
```

**UPDATE:** You'll need to enable .htaccess files, if they are not enabled already... `AllowOverride All` should go in your server config (`All` can be replaced with `FileInfo` later if you don't need *everything*). `Options +FollowSymLinks` must go in either a `<Directory>` section in your server config, or in the .htaccess file itself.

Comment: I tried that and it is still allowing me to download files.  The current contents of the .htaccess file in /files looks like this:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ /index.py [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Try removing the `<IfModule>` container.

Comment: Still doing it.  I'm now do to just:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ /index.py [L]

in the .htaccess file in the /files directory

Comment: Try entering any nonsense (eg. `abcd`) at the top of this .htaccess file - do you get an error?

Comment: I added ABCDEFG at the top of the .htaccess file and restarted apache.  I don't think there was a difference.

Comment: If you entered "ABCDEFG" and nothing happened then your .htaccess file is not being processed at all. (You should have seen a 500 error.) As mentioned in my comment above, have you enabled .htaccess files? ie. `AllowOverride FileInfo` (at least) in your server config. `Options +FollowSymLinks` must also be enabled for per-directory rewrites.

Comment: I guess that I have not.  Where do I do that?  In the httpd.conf file?

Comment: `AllowOverride All` should go in your server config (`All` can be replaced with `FileInfo` later if you don't need _everything_). `Options +FollowSymLinks` must go in either a `<Directory>` section in your server config, or in your .htaccess file itself.